# How can a Wi-Fi client distinguish between ad-hoc and hotspot networks?

Tags: wifi, android-wifi, adhoc

Android does not support ad-hoc WiFi networks. My question is, how can it distinguish between ad-hoc and hotspot networks?

**UPDATE**

In other words, what are protocol differences between ad-hoc and hotspot networks? Or what is the key difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [BSSID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_(802.11_network)#Basic_service_set_identification_.28BSSID.29) of an ad-hoc network is a MAC address flagged as [individual and local](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Individual_address_block) (i.e. the two least-significant bits of the first octet will be "10").